# Good coding practise for Java class

Tags: java

I have a POJO class like below :

```
public class UserInfo {


    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private boolean select;
    private boolean active;


    public UserInfo(){

    }   

    public UserInfo(Integer userId) {
        super();
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        //use userId property 

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //use userId property 
    }

}
```

If I want to search for a given UserInfo object , among a list of users , i am using below code like this :

```
List<UserInfo> users = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();

//users are populated by some means 

Integer userId =  //got externally by a method call 
int index = users.indexOf(new UserInfo(userId)); 

if(index != -1){
    //get user form list 
    UserInfo user = users.get(index);
    // do processing 

}
```

My questions are  :

1)Is it a good coding practise to use a constructor with only one field (used in indexOf method) to search for a given user ? The reason using this 
constructor is since my hashcode and eqauls only checks for userId , only that much information containing object is created.

2)In my code , at lot of places I am making boolean comparison like below :

```
  if(user.isSelect){
    //user is selcted , do some operation 
  }
```

The select value is assigned true only when a certain condition is met elsewhere in code otherwise it is false always.

Since instance variables are automatically initialised to default values when an object is created (so boolean to false), 
 do I still need to initilise the boolean variable explicitely to false when an object is created ? 
 (in point of view of good coding practice ) or is it ok to rely on default in-built mechanism ?

**EDIT 1 :**
As a response to this question being put on hold

I do agree that there might be differences over the answer of this question. 
But here are my questions to all those who are putting this question on hold (particularly in context of this question):

1)This is not a question you will get answer in any book . There is a high chance that many developers might have faced this scenario
2)A developer always looks upon his/her senior developer to learn from him/her since these people have learned from experience which will not typically
  find in any book. 
3)Since a lot of matured/experience developers vist this site , what is wrong in getting suggestion/feedback/answer for a question which is more of a 
  practical experience based ? Putting the question on hold entirely defeats the purpose

Comment: This is really opinion-based. I don't see a problem in doing 1), and I would explicitly initialize them in 2) so it is easier to grasp, but that's just me.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves the status of putting on hold as it is seeking advice for a better coding practise.

Answer (score 3):

1) Seems that you want to search a user among `UserInfo`s by specified userId. Using `HashMap` as your `UserInfo` container is highly recommended here, according to your scenario. Sample code here:

```
List<UserInfo> users = ...;// given a list of UserInfo

//put UserInfo into a HashMap
Map<Integer, UserInfo> userMap = new HashSet<Integer, UserInfo>();
for(UserInfo user :  users) {
    userMap.put(user.getId(), user);
}

int uid = ...;//given a uid
//lookup the user in HashMap by uid
UserInfo user = userMap.get(uid);
```

If you're required to use ArrayList only. The following code works better:

```
List<UserInfo> users = ...;// given a list of UserInfo
long uid = ...;//given a uid
for(UserInfo user :  users) {
    if(user.getId() == uid) {
        //target user found
    }
}
```

This avoids object creating each time you want to search a target user: `users.indexOf(new UserInfo(userId))`

2) You don't have to initiate a `boolean` field if its default value is `false`; But what should we do if the default value of a `boolean` field is `true`? I'll tell you a little skill here, which is picking an opposite word. For example, you need a field to describe if a user is absent from a meeting, if you want a user to be default not-absent, then pick the word `absent` as your field name. Otherwise, if you want a user to be default absent, then pick the  word `present`.

Comment: Change variable to `int`. Java won't autobox *and* cast from `long` to `Integer` in one go. But +1 the map is the right way to go IMHO

Comment: Thank for reminding. My typing mistake. @Bohemian

Comment: @Bohemian:Is map based option has been recommended because of performance dimension ? Using maps will require everytime convert List to Map. Also for arrayList based option , it it not the repeating the same thing provided by java library API ? For second part of answer , it is awsome explanation. +1 for it .

Answer (score 0):

indexOf method is used for searching from a collection. Method is provided by java for the same reason, so yes it is OK to use indexOf method for search.
Though you may need to be cautious for duplicate elements.
indexOf method gives the first occurrence of the element in the list, so if you list contains duplicate elements, you may have to do over riding according to the business needs.

Moreover, if your collection will not have duplicate elements than use Set as they does not support duplicate elements and is the correct form of collection to be used to avoid duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

1. what you want to do is finding an user only by id, i think the following code is better:

> ```
> for(UserInfo user: users){
>     if(user.getId().equals(id)){
>         return user;
>     }
> }
> ```

1. i would explicitly initialize variables because it's meaningful, using default in-built mechanism will make others confused when reading your code.